# Watson Responds with one API code

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

i know if I want send any to Watson in conversation I use the:

```
var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
var context = latestResponse.context;
Api.sendRequest("Hi Watson!", context);
```

This result of my code:

[image]

I want to know how do I get Watson to send something in the conversation. I saw some examples and tried and it did not work. Can someone help?

**I dont now If I'm doing right**, but My example is:

```
// var responseText = null;
   //responseText = {};
 var latestResponse = Api.setResponsePayload(); // I dont know if this is true
  var context = latestResponse.context;
  Api.sendRequest('Hi ' + context); // I try this
  responseText = 'Hi ' + context; // I try this too
```

**This is what i want**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the demo app at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple ?

You can add objects to the context in a JSON way.

```
context.myproperty = "Hello World";
```

And send this with the input to the service

The other way around, inside the conversation service, you can assign a variable (in this case username) to the text provided in the previous step (in this case input.text).
By using `$variablename` (in this case `$username`) you can generate a dynamic response.
Don't let the order in the advance response screen disturb you, context is processed before output...

[image]

In the client (in my case Java)

```
MessageRequest.Builder messageRequestBuilder = new MessageRequest.Builder();
        messageRequestBuilder.inputText("Joe");
        messageRequestBuilder.context(question.context); //this context comes from a previous step 


ServiceCall<MessageResponse> response = conversationService.message(workspaceId, messageRequestBuilder.build());
        MessageResponse mAnswer =  response.execute();

        Object textObject = mAnswer.getOutput().get("text");
```

This textObject will contain: *Hi Joe, nice to meet you. I am here to answer questions about....*

(Node.) JS code copied (and removed some lines )  from the sample app

```
// Create the service wrapper
var conversation = watson.conversation ( {
  username: process.env.CONVERSATION_USERNAME || '<username>',
  password: process.env.CONVERSATION_PASSWORD || '<password>',
  version_date: '2016-07-11',
  version: 'v1'
} );


// Endpoint to be called from the client side
app.post ( '/api/message', function (req, res) {

  var payload = {
    workspace_id: workspace_id,
    context: {}
  };
  if ( req.body ) {
    if ( req.body.input ) {
      payload.input = req.body.input;
    }
    if ( req.body.context ) {
      // The client must maintain context/state
      payload.context = req.body.context;
    }
  }
  // Send the input to the conversation service
  conversation.message ( payload, function (data) {
    return res.json ( data );
  } );
```

Comment: Ok, but, how do I send this in conversation as if it were the bot? In my example, it sends as user... Check my edit

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi I have edited my response, asuming you don't want to decide each time if the conversationservice or another service (e.g. local javascript) gives the anwer

Comment: Hi @mpjjonker, in the case I use javascript e nodejs. You can add one example?