# Maintain Context

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to keep the context in Watson Conversation, but it isn't working.. I already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041442/watson-responds-with-one-api-code), but it didn't worked. I'm trying to integrate the bot to the html.

I tried this in the conversation configuration:

```
var payload = {
workspace_id: workspace,
context: {}}; 
if (req.body) {
 if (req.body.input) {
  payload.input = req.body.input;
}
 if(req.body.context) {
  payload.context = req.body.context;
}}
```

And this in the code to html/javascript:

```
var payload = {};
var context = {}; 

function callWatson(){
alert("watson");
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON',
contentType: "application/json",
url: '/api/message',
data: JSON.stringify(payload)
}).done(function (json) {
if (json.output.text[0]) {
  context = payload.context;
$'<div class="message">+ json.output.text[0]+</div>').appendTo($('.container'));

function insertMessage() {
msg = $('.message-input').val();
$'<div class="message">+ msg+</div>').appendTo($('.container'));
```

I'm a beginner in coding and I tried coping the conversation-simple js, but I wanted something more simple and direct.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try using this as a starting point: https://github.com/snrubnomis/burgerbot

It's intended to be as simple as possible.  The "sendMessage" function (in burgerbot.js) makes the call and then stores the returned context for use on subsequent calls.

Comment: It helped a lot! But I've a question please.. to personalize the <div> I need to change the displayMessage content?

Comment: `displayMessage` constructs the new DOM element which contains the messages (from both user and watson).  If you want to change the content that is displayed for each message then you can do that in this function.  If it's just appearance you want to change then you can do that in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

For send message like Watson, with repository [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple), you can simple add in your front-end:

```
var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
var context = latestResponse.context;
Api.setResponsePayload('{"output": {"text": ["Hi $name!"]},"context" : ' + JSON.stringify(context) +'}');
```

You can see the Javascript code use `Api` and `getResponsePayload()` and `setResponsePayload` function inside api.js (path public/js/api.js) to send a message like Watson. But, in your index you have to add the file for use like this [line](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/public/index.html#L39).

You can see inside my setResponsePayload I use the `output` and `text` to send the message, like payload show if Watson sends a message.

Comment: I'm trying to do with ajax, but I think I'll use the conversation-simple.. tks a lot!

Comment: Yes, my example is with Conversation-simple :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to waste time to maintain context just delete conversation_start dialog(first dialog node) in ibm watson conversation after that give input then you will get exact output